# Two domain for one site not working in mobile

Tags: subdomains, wp-config

I want to have **two different domain** for my site 1) **Desktop** and 2) **Mobile**.

So for 1) **Desktop** : `https://example.com`
       2) **Mobile**  : `https://m.example.com`(Or can say `https://example.com/m`)

---

To **achieve** that, **What I have done so far** :

I have made **sub directory** `m` in to my **main directory** `example.com` and copied all the content of `example.com` in to the `m`.

Next **step** I did is changed the `wp-config.php` of **sub directory** `m` by adding below two lines :

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/m');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/m');
```

And I am using [`Simple Mobile URL Redirect`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/) plugin to **change the URL** when accessing site from **Mobile**.

**PROBLEM** is:

When I check `https://example.com/m` **from desktop**, its working fine and all menu link and path working correctly.

But When I try to go `https://example.com/m` from **mobile**, It is redirect to me to the mobile domain but when I click on **any menu** or **any other page link** (Say for About Us page), then they redirect me to **home page** only(which is `https://example.com/m`).

What might be the **issue**?

**EDITED :**

I have given `https://example.com/m/` path to redirect plugin.If I put `https://example.com/m` (**without trailing slash**) then It is giving me and **Redirect Loop** error and **with trailing slash** it is working fine.

Is that because I have define in `wp-confing.php` **without trailing slash** ?

Ha it to do anything with my main question?

Comment: have you tried using default permalink settings ?

Comment: I am using default permalink setting. If I disable [`Simple Mobile URL Redirect`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/) plugin , then go manually by typing `http://example.com/m` then it is working perfectly fine.